# PHP Parse Yahoo Finance get 505 HTTP error

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php

$feedURL = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("EURUSD","GBPUSD")&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys';

$feedDATA = file_get_contents(urlencode($feedURL));

print_r($feedDATA);


?>
```

I tried to parse yahoo finance for Forex Price feed but I get this error

```
HTTP/1.0 505 HTTP Version Not Supported in /home/site1/public_html/forex/getprice.php on line 12
```

How can I resolve this and parse the xml 1.6551 in the XML for EUR/USD and GBP/USD

**Thanks for helping**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not encode the whole url, only the parameters is necessary to be url encoded.

And PHP has a wonderful **[http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)** function help you build the query string.

***Code:***

```
$feedURL = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
$params = array(
  'q' => 'select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("EURUSD","GBPUSD")',
  'env' => 'store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys'
);

$feedDATA = file_get_contents($feedURL.'?'.http_build_query($params));

print_r($feedDATA);
```

#### How to parse the xml data?

You could even pass the url to `SimpleXMLElement`'s constructor.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($feedURL.'?'.http_build_query($params), null, true);

foreach ($xml->results->rate as $rate) {
  echo $rate->Name . PHP_EOL;
  echo $rate->Rate . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong `urlencode($feedURL)`. I mean you are encoding the whole url!!

```
$feedDATA = file_get_contents($feedURL);
```

You need to encode the query portion of your GET parameter. Here is how:

```
$feedURL = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q='.urlencode('select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("EURUSD","GBPUSD")').'&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys';
```